# function doesn't output anything from the vectors C++

Tags: c++

Basically, i'm working on some coursework which requires me to create a flight booking system that allows for up to two stops e.g. London to Paris to Barcelona to Hamburg. I managed to create a version where 1 stop works e.g. London to Paris to Barcelona but i cannot get this one to work. I have included my code below, whenever i call this function and pass it any two airports, it does not output anything. I appreciate the code below is lengthy but a lot of it is repetitive. I've also probably gone about programming this question the completely wrong way. If you have any better ideas on how to approach this, please do share.

Many thanks.

```
void searchAllFlights(string origin, string destination)
    {

        ifstream checkNumOfLines("flights.txt");
        int numOfLines = 0;

        for(string line; getline(checkNumOfLines, line);){
            numOfLines++;
        }
        int lengthOfLines[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

        checkNumOfLines.clear();
        checkNumOfLines.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        int index = 0;
        for(string line; getline(checkNumOfLines, line);){
            lengthOfLines[index] = line.length();
            index++;
        }

        int filePointers[11] = {0, lengthOfLines[0], lengthOfLines[0] + lengthOfLines[1], lengthOfLines[0] + lengthOfLines[1] + lengthOfLines[2],
            lengthOfLines[0] + lengthOfLines[1] + lengthOfLines[2] + lengthOfLines[3], lengthOfLines[0] + lengthOfLines[1] + lengthOfLines[2] +
            lengthOfLines[3] + lengthOfLines[4], lengthOfLines[0] + lengthOfLines[1] + lengthOfLines[2] +
            lengthOfLines[3] + lengthOfLines[4] + lengthOfLines[5], lengthOfLines[0] + lengthOfLines[1] + lengthOfLines[2] +
            lengthOfLines[3] + lengthOfLines[4] + lengthOfLines[5] + lengthOfLines[6], lengthOfLines[0] + lengthOfLines[1] + lengthOfLines[2] +
            lengthOfLines[3] + lengthOfLines[4] + lengthOfLines[5] + lengthOfLines[6] + lengthOfLines[7], lengthOfLines[0] + lengthOfLines[1] 
        + lengthOfLines[2] + lengthOfLines[3] + lengthOfLines[4] + lengthOfLines[5] + lengthOfLines[6] + lengthOfLines[7] + lengthOfLines[8], 
        lengthOfLines[0] + lengthOfLines[1] + lengthOfLines[2] + lengthOfLines[3] + lengthOfLines[4] + lengthOfLines[5] + lengthOfLines[6] + 
        lengthOfLines[7] + lengthOfLines[8] + lengthOfLines[9]};

        ifstream flights("flights.txt");

        startingDeparturePoint = origin;
        endDestinationPoint = destination;
        totalFlightsPrice = 0;
        totalFlightDuration = 0;

        string originFromFile;
        string destFromFile;
        string airline;
        int price;;
        int flightDuration;

        cout << "No. |" << "Origin |" << "Destination |" << "Airline             |" << "Price         |" << "Duration                 |" << endl;
        cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;

        matches = 0;

        int currentLine = 0;

        while(flights >> originFromFile >> destFromFile >> airline >> price >> flightDuration)
        {
            //flights.seekg(setfilepos, ios::beg);
            int numberOfChars = originFromFile.length() + destFromFile.length() + airline.length();


            if(originFromFile == startingDeparturePoint && destFromFile == endDestinationPoint)
            {
                matches++;
                directFlight(originFromFile, destFromFile, airline, price, flightDuration);
            }

            else if(originFromFile != startingDeparturePoint && destFromFile == endDestinationPoint)
            {
                matches++;

                string stopoverLast = originFromFile;
                string airlineLast = airline;
                int priceLast = price;
                int flightDurationLast = flightDuration;

                int currentIndex = firstOrigins.size() + 1;

                secondOrigins[currentIndex] = stopoverLast;
                secondDests[currentIndex] = destFromFile;
                secondAirlines[currentIndex] = airlineLast;
                secondPrices[currentIndex] = priceLast;
                secondFlightDurations[currentIndex] = flightDurationLast;


                ifstream flights2("flights.txt");

                string originFromFile2;
                string destFromFile2;
                string airlineFromFile2;
                int priceFromFile2;
                int flightDurationFromFile2;

                while(flights2 >> originFromFile2 >> destFromFile2 >> airlineFromFile2 >> priceFromFile2 >> flightDurationFromFile2){//1q
                    if(destFromFile2 == stopoverLast){
                        firstOrigins.push_back(originFromFile2);
                        firstDests.push_back(destFromFile2);
                        firstAirlines.push_back(airlineFromFile2);
                        firstPrices.push_back(priceFromFile2);
                        firstFlightDurations.push_back(flightDurationFromFile2);

                        if(originFromFile2 != startingDeparturePoint){
                            thirdOrigins[currentIndex] = secondOrigins[currentIndex];
                            thirdDests[currentIndex] = secondOrigins[currentIndex];
                            thirdAirlines[currentIndex] = secondOrigins[currentIndex];
                            thirdPrices[currentIndex] = secondPrices[currentIndex];
                            thirdFlightDurations[currentIndex] = secondFlightDurations[currentIndex];

                            secondOrigins[currentIndex] = firstOrigins[currentIndex];
                            secondDests[currentIndex] = firstOrigins[currentIndex];
                            secondAirlines[currentIndex] = firstOrigins[currentIndex];
                            secondPrices[currentIndex] = firstPrices[currentIndex];
                            secondFlightDurations[currentIndex] = firstFlightDurations[currentIndex];

                            ifstream flights3("flights.txt");

                            string originFromFile3;
                            string destFromFile3;
                            string airlineFromFile3;
                            int priceFromFile3;
                            int flightDurationFromFile3;

                            while(flights3 >> originFromFile3 >> destFromFile3 >> airlineFromFile3 >> priceFromFile3 >> flightDurationFromFile3){
                                if(originFromFile3 == startingDeparturePoint && destFromFile3 == secondOrigins[currentIndex]){
                                    firstOrigins[currentIndex] = originFromFile3;
                                    firstDests[currentIndex] = destFromFile3;
                                    firstAirlines[currentIndex] = airlineFromFile3;
                                    firstPrices[currentIndex] = priceFromFile3;
                                    firstFlightDurations[currentIndex] = flightDurationFromFile3;

                                    while(flights3 >> originFromFile3 >> destFromFile3 >> airlineFromFile3 >> priceFromFile3 >> flightDurationFromFile3){
                                        if(originFromFile3 == startingDeparturePoint && destFromFile3 == secondOrigins[currentIndex]){
                                            firstOrigins.push_back(firstOrigins[currentIndex]);
                                            firstDests.push_back(firstDests[currentIndex]);
                                            firstAirlines.push_back(firstAirlines[currentIndex]);
                                            firstPrices.push_back(firstPrices[currentIndex]);
                                            firstFlightDurations.push_back(firstFlightDurations[currentIndex]);

                                            secondOrigins[currentIndex + 1] = secondOrigins[currentIndex];
                                            secondDests[currentIndex + 1] = secondDests[currentIndex];
                                            secondAirlines[currentIndex + 1] = secondAirlines[currentIndex];
                                            secondPrices[currentIndex + 1] = secondPrices[currentIndex];
                                            secondFlightDurations[currentIndex + 1] = secondFlightDurations[currentIndex];

                                            thirdOrigins[currentIndex + 1] = originFromFile3;
                                            thirdDests[currentIndex + 1] = destFromFile3;
                                            thirdAirlines[currentIndex + 1] = airlineFromFile3;
                                            thirdPrices[currentIndex + 1] = priceFromFile3;
                                            thirdFlightDurations[currentIndex + 1] = flightDurationFromFile3;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            currentIndex++;
                            while(flights >> originFromFile >> destFromFile >> airline >> price >> flightDuration){
                                if(originFromFile != startingDeparturePoint && destFromFile == endDestinationPoint){
                                    matches++;

                                    stopoverLast = originFromFile;
                                    airlineLast = airline;
                                    priceLast = price;
                                    flightDurationLast = flightDuration;

                                    secondOrigins[currentIndex] = stopoverLast;
                                    secondDests[currentIndex] = destFromFile;
                                    secondAirlines[currentIndex] = airlineLast;
                                    secondPrices[currentIndex] = priceLast;
                                    secondFlightDurations[currentIndex] = flightDurationLast;

                                    firstOrigins.push_back(originFromFile2);
                                    firstDests.push_back(destFromFile2);
                                    firstAirlines.push_back(airlineFromFile2);
                                    firstPrices.push_back(priceFromFile2);
                                    firstFlightDurations.push_back(flightDurationFromFile2);

                                    while(flights2 >> originFromFile2 >> destFromFile2 >> airlineFromFile2 >> priceFromFile2 >> flightDurationFromFile2){
                                        currentIndex++;
                                        secondOrigins[currentIndex] = stopoverLast;
                                        secondDests[currentIndex] = destFromFile;
                                        secondAirlines[currentIndex] = airlineLast;
                                        secondPrices[currentIndex] = priceLast;
                                        secondFlightDurations[currentIndex] = flightDurationLast;

                                        firstOrigins.push_back(originFromFile2);
                                        firstDests.push_back(destFromFile2);
                                        firstAirlines.push_back(airlineFromFile2);
                                        firstPrices.push_back(priceFromFile2);
                                        firstFlightDurations.push_back(flightDurationFromFile2);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        // loop over vectors and print out results, put in conditional statements to
        //check if 2nd and 3rd flights exist, if they do add the "-----" after

        for(int i = 0; i < firstOrigins.size(); i++){
            int mins = firstFlightDurations[i];
            int hours = 0;

            while(mins >= 60){
                hours++;
                mins -= 60;
            }
                cout << "No. |" << "Origin |" << "Destination |" << "Airline             |" << "Price         |" 
                    << "Duration " << endl;
            if(firstOrigins[i] != "-"){
                cout << left << setw(4) << setfill(' ') << 1 << right << "|";
                cout << left << setw(7) << setfill(' ') << firstOrigins[i] << right << "|";
                cout << left << setw(12) << setfill(' ') << firstDests[i] << right << "|";
                cout << left << setw(20) << setfill(' ') << firstAirlines[i] << right << "|";
                cout << left << "\x9c" << setw(13) << setfill(' ') << left << firstPrices[i] << right << "|";
                cout << left << hours << "hr(s) " << mins << "min(s)" << setw(11) << setfill(' ') << right << "|" << endl;

                if(secondOrigins[i] != "-"){
                    int mins2 = secondFlightDurations[i];
                    int hours2 = 0;

                    while(mins2 >= 60){
                        hours2++;
                        mins2 -= 60;
                    }

                    totalFlightsPrice = firstPrices[i] + secondPrices[i];
                    totalFlightDuration = firstFlightDurations[i] + secondFlightDurations[i] + thirdFlightDurations[i];

                    cout << left << setw(4) << setfill(' ') << 1 << right << "|";
                    cout << left << setw(7) << setfill(' ') << secondOrigins[i] << right << "|";
                    cout << left << setw(12) << setfill(' ') << secondDests[i] << right << "|";
                    cout << left << setw(20) << setfill(' ') << secondAirlines[i] << right << "|";
                    cout << left << "\x9c" << setw(13) << setfill(' ') << left << secondPrices[i] << right << "|";
                    cout << left << hours2 << "hr(s) " << mins2 << "min(s)" << setw(11) << setfill(' ') << right << "|" << endl;

                    if(thirdOrigins[i] != "-"){
                        int mins3 = secondFlightDurations[i];
                        int hours3 = 0;

                        while(mins3 >= 60){
                            hours3++;
                            mins3 -= 60;
                        }

                        totalFlightsPrice = firstPrices[i] + secondPrices[i] + thirdPrices[i];
                        totalFlightDuration = firstFlightDurations[i] + secondFlightDurations[i] + thirdFlightDurations[i];

                        cout << left << setw(4) << setfill(' ') << 1 << right << "|";
                        cout << left << setw(7) << setfill(' ') << thirdOrigins[i] << right << "|";
                        cout << left << setw(12) << setfill(' ') << thirdDests[i] << right << "|";
                        cout << left << setw(20) << setfill(' ') << thirdAirlines[i] << right << "|";
                        cout << left << "\x9c" << setw(13) << setfill(' ') << left << thirdPrices[i] << right << "|";
                        cout << left << hours3 << "hr(s) " << mins3 << "min(s)" << setw(11) << setfill(' ') << right << "|" << endl;

                        int totalmins = totalFlightsPrice;
                        int totalhours = 0;

                        while(totalmins >= 60){
                            totalhours++;
                            totalmins -= 60;
                        }

                        cout << left << setw(4) << setfill(' ') << " " << right << "|";
                        cout << left << setw(7) << setfill(' ') << " " << right << "|";
                        cout << left << setw(12) << setfill(' ') << " " << right << "|";
                        cout << left << setw(20) << setfill(' ') << " " << right << "|";
                        cout << left << setw(13) << setfill(' ') << "Total = \x9c" << totalFlightsPrice << right << "|";
                        cout << left << setw(6) << setfill(' ') << totalhours << "hr(s) " << totalmins << "min(s)"
                            << setw(11) << setfill(' ') << right << "|" << endl;
                        cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
                    }
                    else{

                        int totalmins = totalFlightDuration;
                        int totalhours = 0;

                        while(totalmins >= 60){
                            totalhours++;
                            totalmins -= 60;
                        }

                        cout << left << setw(4) << setfill(' ') << " " << right << "|";
                        cout << left << setw(7) << setfill(' ') << " " << right << "|";
                        cout << left << setw(12) << setfill(' ') << " " << right << "|";
                        cout << left << setw(20) << setfill(' ') << " " << right << "|";
                        cout << left << setw(13) << setfill(' ') << "Total = \x9c" << totalFlightsPrice << right << "|";
                        cout << left << setw(6) << setfill(' ') << totalhours << "hr(s) " << totalmins << "min(s)"
                            << setw(11) << setfill(' ') << right << "|" << endl;
                        cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
                }
            }
            else{
                cout << "No possible flight paths between the airports inputted.";
            }

            currentLine++;

            if(filePointers[currentLine] != filePointers[currentLine - 1]){
                flights.clear();
                flights.seekg(filePointers[currentLine],ios::beg);
            }
        }
```

EDIT: 
You can also ignore the checkNumOfLines file, and the filePointers and lengthOfLines arrays. I thought i had to reset the file pointer for it to print out correctly but nope. Just realised it does output one possible flight path which is if i input the very first origin and destination from the flight path i am reading in to the program.

EDIT 2:
This is giving me way more stress than it should be. i think this whole method i'm using is absurd. Can someone briefly outline an approach they would take to build a command line program that would show you a list of possible flights between two user inputted airport codes, allowing for up to 2 stops please.

NEW APPROACH (Thanks to @PaulMcKenzie and @TonyD):

I basically create 3 vectors, one to hold all the possible flights from the text file, one to hold the flights for the current journey (this gets cleared on each loop) and one which is a multidimensional vector to hold the series of flights as vectors that were in the current journey.

```
class flightSearch
{
public:

    struct Flight
    {
        string origin;
        string destination;
        string airline;
        int price;
        int flightDuration;
    };

    vector<Flight> allFlights;
    vector<Flight> flightsInJourney;
    vector<vector <Flight> > allMatches; 
    Flight f;

    void populateFlightsVector()
    {
        ifstream flightsfile("flights.txt");
        while(flightsfile >> f.origin >> f.destination >> f.airline >> f.price >> f.flightDuration){
            allFlights.push_back(f);
        }
    }

    void searchForARoute(string userOrigin, string userDestination)
    {
        populateFlightsVector();
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < allFlights.size(); i++)
        {
            flightsInJourney.clear();
            if(allFlights[i].origin == userOrigin && allFlights[i].destination == userDestination)
            {
                flightsInJourney.insert(flightsInJourney.begin(), allFlights[i]);
            }
            allMatches.push_back(flightsInJourney);
        }
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < allMatches.size(); i++)
        {
            for(unsigned j = 0; j < allMatches[i].size(); j++){
                cout << allMatches[i][j].origin << " " << allMatches[i][j].destination << " " << allMatches[i][j].airline << endl;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now i should be able add some code to check for routes that require more than one flight as i did in my first attempt and add them to the end multidimensional vector. I've tested this code and it seems to work with direct flights so far. Feel free to call out anything that looks like it could be problematic.

Comment: If you want debugging help a code dump is not going to cut it, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you tried putting in some extra `cout` statements or using a debugger to see exactly where it branches in a way you don't want?  You've posted a lot of code, but not the variable declarations and population code that would make it practical to verify your indexing operations....

Comment: `int lengthOfLines[10] = {};` will create an array of 0s. Your `filePointers` array could be populated using a loop instead of all that manual code.

Comment: `whenever i call this function and pass it any two airports, it does not output anything`  That function you posted is over 300 lines.  Out of all of that, is this the only information you can provide us?  Not anything like "I checked the values of ..." or "in the loop I have the right values...", nothing except "I called the function and it doesn't work"?  Time for you to start debugging and come back with your findings.  Voting to close.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie just set loads of break points and checked the values at each one. The program only manages to perform the function for the first line of the file and then exits with code 0 so it is not crashing. i believe i need to reset the file position at some point but i can't figure out where. i thought where i had put it was correct.

Comment: @TonyD read my comment to Paul please, i've set breakpoints but it only goes through the while loop once for the first line of the file, therefore if the first flight isn't a required matching flight then it doesn't output anything otherwise it'll only output that and quit.

Comment: @air6199 Well step through your program a line at a time until you see it does something that you didn't expect it to do.  Then see why the program diverged from your plans.  You wrote the code, so you had a plan in mind, so see where the code goes against your plan.  There is no excuse in saying "I don't know what went wrong" if you wrote the code -- the only exception to that would be that you're using the language incorrectly and not know it.

Comment: Also, you are reading from a data file.  We have no idea what this file consists of.  We also don't have a main() program to see how you're calling this function.

Comment: *"i believe i need to reset the file position at some point"* - that doesn't sound good... normally you want to read from a file once and save the data into some variables/containers (very often a `std::vector` or `std::map`), then consult the variables repeatedly.  In fact, you have two loops like this `for(string line; getline(checkNumOfLines, line);){` - the second one will already be at the end of that `ifstream` and fail immediately.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the file is set out like this: Origin Dest Airport Price Duration, on each line. The main is basically a menu option and the function is called like so: searchAllFlights(LHR, DXB); these airport codes are user inputted instead

Comment: @TonyD how would i go about saving a file like this in to a container. the structure of the file is: Origin Dest Airline Price Duration, where Price and Duration are ints and the rest are strings

Comment: @air6199 - You should forget about the file and hard-code the information into the program.  That way, we can see a sample of the exact data.  In addition, leave the output for last.  A lot of your code consists of unimportant output statements.  When trying to duplicate an issue, remove the extraneous code -- we all know how `cout` works.  As to how you store the data, have you learned what a `struct` is?

Comment: @air6199: something like `struct Entry { std::string origin_, dest_, airline_; int price_, duration_; }; std::vector<Entry> entries; Entry e; while (my_ifstream >> e.origin_ >> e.dest_ >> e.airline_ >> e.price_ >> e.duration_) entries.push_back(e);`

Comment: @air6199 Please see this link.  It is a copy of what TonyD provided:  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f0e88f90eef2713  This also shows that you build a program *slowly* from the ground up.  You don't write 300+ lines of code in one shot, and then cross your fingers and hope it works.  Learn each aspect (file reading/writing/structs) by testing smaller programs to get familiar with the concepts.

Comment: @TonyD this is a game changer! i didn't know you could essentially create a vector of structs. so now i should be able to make two structs, one for all the lines in the file and one for flights that match the users input?

Comment: @air6199: "make two structs, one for all the lines in the file and one for flights that match the users input?" - well, the former will be a `vector` of `struct`s, and for the latter - if you're just `cout`-ing the matches you don't necessarily need to keep them in a `vector` for later use, but if you see a benefit from keeping the matches around for further processing then sure - use another `vector` of `struct`.  List to Paul too - lots of sound advice above.

Comment: @air6199 You need the structs for the data.  Make sure you run the program TonyD and I posted first to understand the concept of what the vector of structs does.  Then add to that code that searches the vector of structs for the source/destination entry.  You don't need fancy output right now, just a simple test code.  If you don't know how to search correctly -- then that's ok.  Just ask (or start a new question with the simplified code with your attempt).  Once you have that, then you fill in the output fluff.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've built the rest of the program up slowly and tested as I went along, it's just I've written a variety of code to try and get this section of the program working and it's really starting to annoy me, plus it being 3 in the morning is not doing me any good. Hopefully I'll find an approach that works soon!

Comment: Well, believe it or not, the code I posted is at least a good chunk of the program you are trying to write (reading the data in).  The other piece is the search piece, and that is not that difficult.  You will see quite quickly that at least half the code you started out with gets eliminated.

Comment: @TonyD yep I'll need the data for if the user wants to actually book a flight so I'll have to keep an index integer that will correspond to each flight in the vector that will be accessed by matchedEnteries[selectedIndex];

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think I've already got the outline of the program in my head, I can see how you and Tony have helped! I completely overlooked structs! Thank you both for your help! I'll update once I've rewritten this by the weekend hopefully

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie included my code as an edit which uses a struct.

Comment: @TonyD added my new attempt which includes the multiple vectors i was trying to explain. I believe it works in theory, just need to add some code to test it.

Comment: @air6199: looks like you're on the right track!  Have a go at the flights with stop-overs and let us know if you get stuck.  Cheers.

Comment: @TonyD just got a version to work with one stopover, same principle should work for 2 stopovers. The only thing that is bugging me is when i did a for loop over the allFlights vector within the first for loop over the same vector, both using the format, for(unsigned i = 0; i < allFlights.size(); i++){...}, the first one works but the second one (unsigned i = i1 this time) gets stuck in an infinite loop and does not even give i1 a value. I managed to get this working by using for(auto & element: allFlights){...}. I can't see why i had to though, any ideas?

Comment: @air6199 Can you show your main() program?  Also, you only need to populate the vector once, so I don't know why you have it inside of the search function.  It should be called one time in main().  Also, your loop in the search function looks strange -- you're adding `flightsInJourney` to the `allMatches` vector after every flight you found.  That doesn't seem right -- aren't you supposed to build up the flightsInJourney vector first, and when you've found all of them *then* you add it to the `allMatches` vector?

Answer (score 0):

With your latest code, here are the issues that I see that would cause some problems.

First, you don't need to have an `flightsInJourney` vector as a global variable, and thus repeatedly having to clear the vector in your `searchForARoute` function.  You can make it local to your `searchForARoute` function, since all you're using it for is to collect all of the matching flights, and then copy these flights to your `allMatches` vector.

Second, you call `populateFlightsVector` in your search function, but that is not necessary.  You are supposed to be populating the data file once and only once, not repeatedly.  Better to put this in `main()` or similar function that gets called only once to set up your data.

Third, going back to the `searchForARoute` function, your loop to collect the flights that you find is not correct.  You're supposed to collect all the flights found in a local vector first, and then when finished, you `push_back` this vector of found flights onto your `allMatches` vector.

So in a nutshell, the function would probably look more like this:

```
    void searchForARoute(const string& userOrigin, 
                         const string& userDestination)
    {
        vector<Flight> flightsInJourney;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < allFlights.size(); i++)
        {
            if(allFlights[i].origin == userOrigin && allFlights[i].destination == userDestination)
                flightsInJourney.push_back(allFlights[i]);
        }
        // push back all of the found matches
        allMatches.push_back(flightsInJourney);

        for(size_t i = 0; i < allMatches.size(); i++)
        {
            for(size_t j = 0; j < allMatches[i].size(); j++)
                cout << allMatches[i][j].origin << " " << allMatches[i] [j].destination << " " << allMatches[i][j].airline << endl;
        }
     }
```